# Selecting potential store locations based on population of homes in a county

Tags: python, cluster-computing, k-means, genetic-algorithm

I have a 3D numpy array of size (20, 150, 150), representing an area with 150 grids in the x direction, 150 grids in the y direction, and 20 grids (or layers) in the z direction. Each layer has a different distribution of population. I want to find optimal locations for six stores within this area, considering two requirements:

1. Each of the three predefined population ranges (poor_class, fair_class, and good_class) must contain at least two stores.
2. The stores must be spread across the entire region of the county, rather than concentrated in one small location. It should be mentioned that the store opened at the first layer would be the same store and in the same i and j index for all the below z layers of that surface (or 1st layer) host grid.
   I have attempted various approaches, such as clustering and K-means, but have not been successful. I am now considering using a genetic algorithm, but I am open to other suggestions.

Ideally, the output should provide a heatmap of the first layer with the proposed locations of the six stores. However, I am unsure how to upload my .npy population data.

Any guidance on how to approach or solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define your population ranges (classes)
poor_class = (np.min(all_population), 100)
fair_class = (100, 200)
good_class = (200, np.max(all_population))

# Generate random population data (replace this with your actual data)
population_data = np.random.randint(low=0, high=250, size=(20, 150, 150))

# Function to check if a location satisfies the requirements
def is_valid_location(location):
    # Check requirement 1: Each population range should have at least 2 stores
    for pop_range in [poor_class, fair_class, good_class]:
        count = np.sum((population_data[0] >= pop_range[0]) & (population_data[0] < pop_range[1]) & (location == 1))
        if count < 2:
            return False

    # Check requirement 2: Stores should be spread across the region
    if np.sum(location) < 6:
        return False

    return True

# Function to generate a heatmap of the first layer with store locations
def generate_heatmap_with_store_locations(locations):
    heatmap_data = population_data[0].copy()
    heatmap_data[locations != 1] = np.nan

    plt.imshow(heatmap_data, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()

# Genetic algorithm implementation
# You can use any library or implement your own genetic algorithm here

# Sample code to generate random store locations (replace with your genetic algorithm implementation)
store_locations = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(150, 150))
while not is_valid_location(store_locations):
    store_locations = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(150, 150))

# Generate heatmap with store locations
generate_heatmap_with_store_locations(store_locations)
```

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data  which produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.